# Space character is not working with tabularFigures

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a slider widget with the value displayed on the same line in a row. I am using `FontFeature.tabularFigures()` to display my text as monospace but it does not work well with space characters.

When the value goes from two characters to one and vice versa, from 10 to 9 for example, the layout jumps because 9 is only one character wide. I've tried to add a space character to account for this and make it '2' characters but it does not work. Tested on both Android and iOS.

Any idea how I should do this?

My code:

`parent.dart`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Title'),
      subtitle: Column(
        children: List.generate(itemsArray.length, (index) =>
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(itemsArray[index].name),
                Item(itemsArray[index]),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

`item.dart`

```dart
double value = 10.0;

Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 40.0,
      child: Slider.adaptive(
        value: value,
        onChanged: (v) {
          setState(() {
            value = v.floorToDouble();
          });
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 99,
        divisions: 99,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      value.toString().length < 2
          ? '\u00A0$value' //\u00A0 is a no-break space
          : value.toString(),
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontFeatures: [FontFeature.tabularFigures()],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Also `FontFeature.tabularFigures()` doesn't seem to working at all for me in dartpad.dartlang.org

Edit: Added the parent code of the widget with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping your Text widget in a [FittedBox widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html), and setting the FittedBox’s fit property to BoxFit.fitWidth, so that your Text widget takes the full width available to it.

Also you could wrap the Text widget in a SizedBox and set the SizedBox’s width, if you want a specific width.

Comment: FittedBox does not work and using SizedBox cuts off the text when text size in the OS is set to larger than the default

Comment: A Flexible Widget, with fit property set to FlexFit.tight, might work.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Comment: wrapping the `Text` with a `Flexible` causes an error https://pastebin.com/DSyTFa0D